# Appropriate way to print invoice from Java swing application

Tags: java, swing, printing

I need to print an invoice from Java swing application in Unicode (Hebrew chars) and some graphic elements, logo, etc. What is appropriate way to do it?

1. Format manually string (by the way how can I do it?) and send it to printer?
2. Create JPanel and print it? JPanel shouldn't be visible only printable, can I implement it?

I prohibited to use external libraries for this task, otherwise I have implemented it by using DynamicReports. 
Thank you very much for any advise.

Comment: You can print JTable and JTextComponents using the [print method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/swing.html).

Comment: Printing a JFrame and its components     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764634/printing-a-jframe-and-its-components