# Getting High Resolution Image from JPanel

Tags: java, swing, awt

Suppose I have a `JPanel` Called `panel`, and already with a `paintComponent`, I drew some shapes like rectangles. I can get a buffered image out of my panel like:

```
    int w = panel.getWidth();
    int h = panel.getHeight();
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
    panel.paint(g);
    ImageIO.write(bi1, "png", new File("test.png"));
```

How can I get a High Resolution image out of my `panel`? (the current output image is just based on the resolution of my `JPanel` in my monitor)

I tried `AffineTransform`, but it doesn't do what I need.

Note that I already drew everything in my `panel`, and do not want to change my drawing in my `paintComponent` method.

I am really searching for a practical way, and appreciate any help.

Comment: First, use `print` or `printAll` instead of `paint`

Comment: Define "high resolution"

Comment: *"I tried `AffineTransform`, but it doesn't do what I need."*  If it doesn't do what you need, then I don't understand what you need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two possible ways you might achieve this, you could physically resize the component or you could apply an `AffineTransform` to the `Graphics` context, there are problems with both...

So, starting with this screen...

[image: Default]

The background image is quite large to start with and has been scaled down (roughly) to fit within the current component, this is important for what's about to come...

I then resized it by 4 (this should, roughly, get you to around 300dpi)

```
Dimension original = tp.getSize();

System.out.println("Original = " + original);

int width = tp.getWidth() * 4;
int height = tp.getHeight() * 4;

System.out.println("Target = " + width + "x" + height);
tp.setSize(width, height);
tp.doLayout();
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
tp.print(g2d);
g2d.dispose();

tp.setSize(original);
tp.doLayout();

try {
    ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File("Test.png"));
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which resulted in...

[image]

Well, okay, the background image looks cool, but the text is off...

Okay, so instead, we could use an `AffineTransform`...

```
int width = tp.getWidth() * 4;
int height = tp.getHeight() * 4;

BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
g2d.setTransform(AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(4, 4));
tp.print(g2d);
g2d.dispose();

try {
    ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File("Test.png"));
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which resulted in...

[image]

Okay, now the image looks crap and the text is okay...

---

And for reference, the test code...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class HiRes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new HiRes();
    }

    public HiRes() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                final TestPane tp = new TestPane();
                JButton print = new JButton("Print");
                print.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                        Dimension original = tp.getSize();

                        System.out.println("Original = " + original);

                        int width = tp.getWidth() * 4;
                        int height = tp.getHeight() * 4;

                        System.out.println("Target = " + width + "x" + height);
                        tp.setSize(width, height);
                        tp.doLayout();
                        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                        Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
                        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
                        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
                        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
                        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
                        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
                        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
                        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
//                      g2d.setTransform(AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(4, 4));
                        tp.print(g2d);
                        g2d.dispose();
                        tp.setSize(original);
                        tp.doLayout();

                        try {
                            ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File("Test.png"));
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(tp);
                frame.add(print, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage background;

        public TestPane() {

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            try {
                background = ImageIO.read(new File("/some/image/some/where"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            JLabel label = new JLabel("This is a test");
            label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(24f));
            add(label);

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (background != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                Image scaled = background;
                if (getWidth() < getHeight()) {
                    scaled = background.getScaledInstance(getWidth(), -1, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
                } else {
                    scaled = background.getScaledInstance(-1, getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
                }
                int x = (getWidth() - scaled.getWidth(this)) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - scaled.getHeight(this)) / 2;
                g2d.drawImage(scaled, x, y, this);
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: YOU ARE JUST AWESOME. Second method worked in my case perfectly. Would you please explain it more to me what is happening there?

Comment: It's just a simple case of up scaling.  Essentially, you create a `BufferedImage` which meets you desired size (4x in this case), you apply a `AffineTransform` to the `Graphics` context with a scaled transformation of the desired scale (4x) and paint the component to the `BufferedImage`'s `Graphics`, the API takes care of the rest

Answer (score 1):

1. Use print instead of paint
2. Scale up your component and your image dimension, then scale your image back to target size
3. Use transform will make your image blurring, try to scale your image 8 times and you'll see the differences