# How to make a JPanel into a BufferedImage Java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, bufferedimage, turtle-graphics

I have a half-working paint/turtle graphics program but I am having a few issues.
I am going to need to save the image that is drawn at some point - I know I need to use a BufferedImage but how do I go about this? I have attached a little bit of my code below.

In short I have a JFrame with a text field and a white JPanel below it. When commands are typed in by the user lines are drawing through another class and appear on the JPanel. I know I won't be able to save them off the JPanel to an image but have no understanding of how to implement a buffered image and what i would/wouldn't need to change.

Please be kind, I am new to programming and haven't finished some parts of my code yet.

Thanks in advance

```
public class Turtle2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener, KeyListener{

    JMenuBar menuBar;
    JMenu help, file;
    JPanel panel, panel2;
    JMenuItem newO, load, save, exitO, about;
    JTextField text;
    int savecounter = 0, newcounter = 1, part2I = 0;
    int x1 = 0, x2 = 0, y1 = 0, y2 = 0;
    int trigger = 1, turnleftconstant = 0, turnrightconstant =0, direction =0;
    int col = 0;

        public  Turtle2() {
            setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            setSize(1000, 1000);
            setTitle("Graphic");
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        //menu bar

            //sets up general look of window
            panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setBackground(Color.darkGray); 

            //implements box layout
            panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

            //sets up drawing area
            panel2 = new JPanel();
            panel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));;
            panel2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            panel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.darkGray, 3));

            //starting point on drawing area co-ordinates
            x1 = 15; x2 = 15; y1 = 230; y2 =230;

            //starting point implemented
            LinePen first = new LinePen(x1, y1, x2, y2, col);
            panel2.add(first);

            //sets up user input text box
            text = new JTextField(30);

            //add action listener to text box - ready for input and details responses
            text.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                         //retrieves user input
                         String actions = text.getText();
                         first.setVisible(true);

                        //commands from text

                //add the command line textfeild to the interface
                panel.add(text);

                //uses border layout to set the layout of the interface
                getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, panel);
                getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel2);

                //set the size of the interface
                setSize(600,600);
                //ensure the interface is visible
                setVisible(true);

                }
```

Comment: You could do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26923282/getting-high-resolution-image-from-jpanel/26923692#26923692) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984207/cannot-convert-current-canvas-data-into-image-in-java/12984332#12984332), but a better image to store the information you need in order to re-create the image and paint it directly to a `BufferedImage`

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 3) More direct to the problem, create a buffered image the required size, call `getGraphics` to get the graphics context of the image, pass the graphics object to `panel.paint(graphics);`, dispose of the graphics object.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep an array of all your lines, then iterate through them, and then use `img.createGraphics()` to draw your lines and other graphics.