# Printing a jframe in java

Tags: java, swing

I would like to print a jframe when clicking a button.

So i tried this code. If I click the print button, I get a printer dialog and when I tell it to print, it just prints a blank document, i don't know why. Any help?

```
public static class Printer implements Printable {
    final Component comp;

    public Printer(Component comp){
        this.comp = comp;
    }

    @Override
    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat format, int page_index)
            throws PrinterException {
        if (page_index > 0) {
            return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }

        // get the bounds of the component
        Dimension dim = comp.getSize();
        double cHeight = dim.getHeight();
        double cWidth = dim.getWidth();

        // get the bounds of the printable area
        double pHeight = format.getImageableHeight();
        double pWidth = format.getImageableWidth();

        double pXStart = format.getImageableX();
        double pYStart = format.getImageableY();

        double xRatio = pWidth / cWidth;
        double yRatio = pHeight / cHeight;

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.translate(pXStart, pYStart);
        g2.scale(xRatio, yRatio);
        comp.paint(g2);

        return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
}
```

and in the button action performed

```
 JFrame yourComponent = new ODietListJFrame();
    PrinterJob pjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    PageFormat preformat = pjob.defaultPage();
    preformat.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);
    PageFormat postformat = pjob.pageDialog(preformat);

    //If user does not hit cancel then print.
    if (preformat != postformat) {
        //Set print component
        pjob.setPrintable(new Printer(yourComponent), postformat);
        if (pjob.printDialog()) {
            try {
                pjob.print();
            } catch (PrinterException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ODietListJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: To start with, don't call paint, call print

Comment: Something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764634/printing-a-jframe-and-its-components/12765916#12765916)

Comment: I have tried to call print once and printall once again and nothing changed

Comment: Have you tried making the frame visible first?

Comment: Unfortunately, i am a beginner, so can you tell me how to make the frame visible? if you mean to use setvisible is true, so yes i do it.

Comment: Can any one help me?